# What is the safest way to retain some value without a postback control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model:

```
 public class Attribute
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value{ get; set; }
 }
```

Let's say my view will display `@model IEnumerable<MyCustomer.ViewModels.Attribute>`, I want to make a `EditorFor` for my key and value but I just want to retain my Id without after a postback without putting it into a postback control.  How can I acheive this? I know I can put it in a hidden but a hidden can be modified and I'm not sure it's the safest thing to do.  I am passing a new[] of attributes to my view and the Id needs to be preset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following post offers up an approach to the problem by creating a secure hash of the value for the hidden field.

The post also links to an article with sourcecode for a SecuredValueHtmlHelper which sounds like just what you need.

[Prevent change of hidden field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840221/prevent-change-of-hidden-field)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I acheive this?

There are no miracles in the way HTML works. Whatever you put in your HTML form you get back on postback. Whatever you omit, you loose.

So you have a couple of possibilities:

- Store the value in an ASP.NET Session variable so that you could retrieve later.
- Use the Key and Value properties that were sent on postback to query your datastore and the Id (this would work only if the Key/Value couple is unique and has a corresponding Id property in your datastore).
- Store the value of the Id property in an encrypted cookie that you could retrieve on postback. You could use the `FormsAuthentication.Encrypt/Decrypt` methods for this.