# Alternatives to HiddenFor on form submits?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

Currently, I'm passing a model to a submit page as a kind of "default value" for a form. I'm using HiddenFor on the form to make sure that it gets passed, and that works just fine.

However, a smart user could unhide the input and edit it. Is there any alternative to HiddenFor or a way to make sure this value is persisting short of doing expensive validation server side?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you pass a value to the server and not validate it? IMO, disallowing unchecked input into your application is not "expensive", it is vital.

Comment: you can store it on a javascript varible but nonetheless, as long as it is in client side it can be manipulated. You can store it on Session Storage perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to provide your actual implementation details to get a more targeted answer. However, some things can be said:

1) assuming that you have the hidden field with a "default value" that is required when submitting the form, not having it in the form means the controller actions gets nothing and assumes default value

2) if your hidden field value is computed on the client side based on some other fields, the computation might be performed on the server side

If your particular case cannot be covered by above, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2840269/2780791) may help you.

Comment: That secured hidden field looks like exactly what I want. Thanks!